# Openssl decryption displays extra characters

Tags: php, objective-c, encryption, openssl

I want to send and receive encrypted data from a PHP application to iOS and vice versa.

Everything runs fine until i decrypt the string received from iOS application, it adds extra characters on display in PHP, for instance when a string (foo) is encrypted in iOS, here is the output i get in PHP.

```
foo¤º   ¤º  äØKŒCarrier+†7†ÐHÀ€ôa$aLa°aTa(aX¿€<a@aèaaTwaØwaäwa0®50‡4€B4ÀB4°†4ð†4þ;Ð}2}20¸>@¸> ¸>LGa¿
```

The character foo exist in the decrypted string, but with lot of extra character.

I am wondering if this is iOS issue or PHP & if it is IOS what could be the possible issue? is it encoding, padding or any other?

P.S: iOS application is using RSA_PKCS1_PADDING, when i use RSA_NO_PADDING with other character here is the output i get.

```
foodrrrrrrøžäØKŒJustify (Undo action name)äØKŒ!Raise Baseline (Undo action name)äØKŒClear Recent Searches?0xÔ\Õ8Ò|Ó`œšÕØf”œš€œšÔ
```

Notice the string `Justify (Undo action name)` , `Raise Baseline (Undo action name)` what could be the possible issue here?

**Update :**
Here is my PHP Code:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$encrypt = Model_SSL::getInstance()->encrypt("PankeshRaj@iOS");
echo Model_SSL::getInstance()->decrypt("nhXQ7Yg1o5GzhXLe6x1LoKxK/Sg5qPDdA4SCtuH5LIp2klEPKQLAsOf+2ODg+A30k3EzyAjH+xKun9x4HPNIb67ETe4+84oMTPCk5TTuxOrSMNOjwm6L4mp01frOfT/OOcKvtCs+IuW3fWbbvbw/sgecDMG0IuuhsWvvL9FaOpLXkT8vGBOYh7pQH8Gkworf/dnonf/Rfk1vUYWkWlK7n/ycbl7uVVyIO+v3tcKfDdJuEvr4qOd5z3h323i7zvuHbt04WyPrV9Pjk0Zd9C2xte/K5bGHHTlRNZCEdLp5jhB9r7ljL4ToCpAiKSaBeG0HktXjDdW4+X1piPHox6e9Gw==");
```

And here is my Model_SSL

```
<?php
class Model_SSL
{
    protected $publicKey;

    protected $privateKey;

    protected static $ssl;

    private function __construct()
    {
        $this->publicKey = file_get_contents(APPLICATION_PATH.'/../resources/ssl_keys/key.pub');
        $this->privateKey = file_get_contents(APPLICATION_PATH.'/../resources/ssl_keys/private.pem');
    }

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (!isset(self::$ssl)) {
            self::$ssl = new self;
        }
        return self::$ssl;
    }

    public function encrypt($string)
    {
        openssl_public_encrypt($string, $cryptedText, $this->publicKey);
        return base64_encode($cryptedText);
    }

    public function decrypt($string)
    {
        $string = base64_decode($string);
        openssl_private_decrypt($string, $decryptedText, $this->privateKey);
        return $decryptedText;
    }
}
```

For Objective-c i am trying with a sample library, which is quite very lengthy to post here, here is the link to library which i am using : https://github.com/jslim89/RSA-Example

Comment: What headers are you using with your php? it should be set to `UTF-8`.

Comment: I am not sending any headers, let me try setting this

Comment: @l'L'l The output is like this when i set the headers `foodrrrrrr�����K�Justify (Undo action name)��K�!Raise Baseline (Undo action name)��K�Clear Recent Searches?0x�\�8�|�`����f�������`

Comment: Post your code, that would be more helpful.

Comment: @l'L'l Updated with code

Comment: The extra strings tacked on to the encrypted string are from WebKit — they look like the localized strings. So something is messed up at that part.

Comment: Tried in Safari, Chrome & Firefox, i have issue in all 3 browsers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to implement a function to remove padding by including the string length in encrypted string.

I have explained it here [OpenSSL encryption padding issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25278307/openssl-encryption-padding-issue)