# OpenSSL encryption padding issue

Tags: php, objective-c, openssl, padding

I am sending openssl encrypted string from server using PHP to iOS and vice versa, in server using PHP i need to encrypt/decrypt the string and same with iOS, everything works fine except the string received from iOS contains extra characters, after few searches i came to understand that RSA encryption applies PKCS1 padding by default, which appends extra characters to encrypted string for example.

The encrypted string foo is getting this output after decryption.

```
foo¤º   ¤º  äØKŒCarrier+†7†ÐHÀ€ôa$aLa°aTa(aX¿€<a@aèaaTwaØwaäwa0®50‡4€B4ÀB4°†4ð†4þ;Ð}2}20¸>@¸> ¸>LGa¿
```

I was expecting PHP to take care of removing those unwanted padding from the string, but unfortunately it doesn't, the only workaround i can think of is to send the length along the string and strip of those unwanted characters, for example the decrypted string will look like this after adding the length.

```
3_foo¤º   ¤º  äØKŒCarrier+†7†ÐHÀ€ôa$aLa°aTa(aX¿€<a@aèaaTwaØwaäwa0®50‡4€B4ÀB4°†4ð†4þ;Ð}2}20¸>@¸> ¸>LGa¿
```

I can get the initial `3_` which is the length of the string, and remove the rest.

I want to know from you if this is okay to go approach or if there is any other alternative or if PHP should be doing this for me automatically.

If you want to have a look at the code i am using, here it is in another post : [Openssl decryption displays extra characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25260077/openssl-decryption-displays-extra-characters)

Thanks for your reply.

Comment: *"The encrypted string foo is getting this ..."* - yes, you need to include a length. What happens when encryption happens to generate a 0x00 byte so the string appears to be terminated early? Or, Base64 encode it so the embedded NULL is encoded.

Comment: I am not really sure what happens on iOS side, generally we are using inbuilt objective-c function to encrypt using PKCS1 padding, when i receive the string i get length along so i strip rest of string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those having trouble with removing padding here is what i did for the solution.

1. I added string length at the beginning of each string, my string looked like :

   9_foostring¤º   ¤º  äØKŒCarrier+†7†ÐHÀ€ôa$aL°aTa(aX¿€@¸>
2. Get the length prefix from beginning of the string in this case `9_`
3. Split the string without the length prefix, now my string looked like :

   foostring¤º   ¤º  äØKŒCarrier+†7†ÐHÀ€ôa$aL°aTa(aX¿€@¸>
4. Get the first 9 character of the string and strip the rest.

This solved my issue, hope this helps someone too with the similar problem.